# Where can I find resources on VectorScript programming language?

Tags: resources, pascal, cad

Where one can learn more about VectorScript (the Pascal-like programming languaged built into NNA VectorWorks CAD application) to create custom "plug-in" objects and tools ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "official" documentation wiki is now at http://developer.vectorworks.net. It's also worth subscribing to the mailing lists at http://lists.nemetschek.net, and reviewing the [forums](http://techboard.vectorworks.net/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=13&page=1).